# I'm Programming a sticky note that won't stick

Tags: html, css

I want to make a sticky note for my site that changes it's length depending on how much text it has, these are the graphics

http://www.smackjeeves.com/images/uploaded/comics/a/9/a9bb813fajYqH.png

http://img2.smackjeeves.com/images/uploaded/comics/e/a/eafa194f44yHh.png

http://www.smackjeeves.com/images/uploaded/comics/4/f/4fcc68191cLbT.png

I looked at some examples and this is my css code for the div

```
 #sticky-note 
 {
  background-image:url('http://www.smackjeeves.com/images/uploaded/comics/a/9/a9bb813fajYqH.png'), 
                   url('http://img2.smackjeeves.com/images/uploaded/comics/e/a/eafa194f44yHh.png'),
                   url('http://www.smackjeeves.com/images/uploaded/comics/4/f/4fcc68191cLbT.png');
  background-position: top, center, bottom;
  background-repeat:no-reapeat, repeat-y, no-repeat;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 170px;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

but it doesn't work, i want the middle graphic to repeat vertically and the top and bottom ones to stay the same at the top, help

Comment: 'sticky' and 'note' are not very good tags. You should tag the question with the technologies you are using, for example, 'css' would be the best tag for this question.

Comment: You should just make the sticky note with css3 (i.e. gradient, box-shadow, border-radius).

Comment: thanks, i'll re-tag it. and i'm not really sure how to do this type of stuff with css3, i mean slanted edge and square shaped shadow

Answer (score 3):

Use three separate divs, a header that contains the top part, a footer with the bottom, and a content one that stretches the middle.

Comment: yeah but that's too much trouble, i'm building in a comment feature and i want people to be able to use it so i might turn it into a blockquote or something and it's too confusing to go div div blah blah blah div

Comment: @CalebM - If it were easy we wouldn't be getting paid for it.

Comment: As in it's our job as web developers/designers.